# Re-installed Steam; can't download tenfoot_dicts_all.zip

Tags: steam, technical-issues

I re-installed Steam and the installation went fine but when I try to run it the update bar jumps back to zero and an error message pops up.

[image: error message gif]

Here's the contents of `bootstrap_log`.

```
[2017-02-27 15:03:55] Startup - updater built Jun 14 2016 16:24:24
[2017-02-27 15:03:55] Verifying installation...
[2017-02-27 15:03:55] Unable to read and verify install manifest C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\package\steam_client_win32.installed
[2017-02-27 15:03:55] Verification complete
[2017-02-27 15:03:55] Downloading update...
[2017-02-27 15:03:55] Checking for available updates...
[2017-02-27 15:03:55] Package file tenfoot_dicts_all.zip.87bb49891925214df2d745e12a53518fd2ea86f0 missing or incorrect size
[2017-02-27 15:03:55] Downloading update (0 of 11,987 KB)...
[2017-02-27 15:03:56] Downloading update (31 of 11,987 KB)...
[2017-02-27 15:03:56] Downloading update (127 of 11,987 KB)...
[2017-02-27 15:03:56] Downloading update (243 of 11,987 KB)...
[2017-02-27 15:03:56] Downloading update (374 of 11,987 KB)...
[2017-02-27 15:03:57] Downloading update (478 of 11,987 KB)...
[2017-02-27 15:03:57] Downloading update (572 of 11,987 KB)...
[2017-02-27 15:03:57] Downloading update (675 of 11,987 KB)...
[2017-02-27 15:03:57] Downloading update (745 of 11,987 KB)...
[2017-02-27 15:03:58] Downloading update (855 of 11,987 KB)...
[2017-02-27 15:03:58] Downloading update (940 of 11,987 KB)...
[2017-02-27 15:03:58] Downloading update (961 of 11,987 KB)...
[2017-02-27 15:03:58] Error: Download of package (tenfoot_dicts_all) failed after 0 bytes (200).
[2017-02-27 15:03:58] Downloading update (0 of 11,987 KB)...
[2017-02-27 15:03:58] Package file tenfoot_dicts_all.zip.87bb49891925214df2d745e12a53518fd2ea86f0 missing or incorrect size
[2017-02-27 15:03:59] Downloading update (62 of 11,987 KB)...
[2017-02-27 15:03:59] Downloading update (190 of 11,987 KB)...
[2017-02-27 15:03:59] Downloading update (309 of 11,987 KB)...
[2017-02-27 15:03:59] Downloading update (498 of 11,987 KB)...
[2017-02-27 15:04:00] Downloading update (658 of 11,987 KB)...
[2017-02-27 15:04:00] Downloading update (779 of 11,987 KB)...
[2017-02-27 15:04:00] Downloading update (956 of 11,987 KB)...
[2017-02-27 15:04:00] Error: Download of package (tenfoot_dicts_all) failed after 0 bytes (200).
[2017-02-27 15:04:00] Downloading update (0 of 11,987 KB)...
[2017-02-27 15:04:00] Package file tenfoot_dicts_all.zip.87bb49891925214df2d745e12a53518fd2ea86f0 missing or incorrect size
[2017-02-27 15:04:01] Downloading update (39 of 11,987 KB)...
[2017-02-27 15:04:01] Downloading update (126 of 11,987 KB)...
[2017-02-27 15:04:01] Downloading update (247 of 11,987 KB)...
[2017-02-27 15:04:01] Downloading update (384 of 11,987 KB)...
[2017-02-27 15:04:02] Downloading update (474 of 11,987 KB)...
[2017-02-27 15:04:02] Downloading update (597 of 11,987 KB)...
[2017-02-27 15:04:02] Downloading update (731 of 11,987 KB)...
[2017-02-27 15:04:02] Downloading update (856 of 11,987 KB)...
[2017-02-27 15:04:03] Error: Download of package (tenfoot_dicts_all) failed after 0 bytes (200).
[2017-02-27 15:04:03] Downloading update (0 of 11,987 KB)...
[2017-02-27 15:04:03] Repeatedly failed to download packages, giving up
[2017-02-27 15:04:03] Error: Steam needs to be online to update. Please confirm your network connection and try again.
[2017-02-27 15:04:05] Shutdown
```

I found some websites saying that changing to google's DNS server solved the problem for some people. I tried that, but it didn't work. I also contacted Steam support but they just gave me generic network troubleshooting advice.

It seems to me like there's a problem on their end.

Comment: I guess this could be related to AWS’ problems yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this page](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/fix-steam-is-temporarily-unavailable-please-try-later-by-changing-download-region/) about getting the files from the origin server if the CDNs weren't working. While you could directly follow the instructions on that page, I found it was easier to just download the file directly by pre-pending the needed file with `cdn-01-origin.steampowered.com/client/`

So in my case going to `cdn-01-origin.steampowered.com/client/tenfoot_dicts_all.zip.87bb49891925214df2d745e12a53518fd2ea86f0` let me download the file directly for later copying into the `Steam/packages` folder

The site also mentions `cdn-01.steampowered.com` but that didn't work when I tried it.